# No access to dashboard

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to use my delegate account (The principal account is managed by the enterprise owner) to access the PayPal developer and everything is fine until I click on the dashboard link. I'm getting a **403** error message.

Last year I was working with the same account and it was fine. I'm wondering if something have changed since the last time i used the dashboard feature? Did my user need more permissions to access the PayPal developer dashboard?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if 'delegate' meaning authorized alias user ID; than in 'most' cases I have seen where one couldn't even log into the developer portal with their ALIAS ID. That said, I am aware that only the principal account owner may log into the developer portal using their email and password.

The permissions of an alias cannot be altered to allow such access even if they have the highest permissions on the account itself; ADMIN.

It is possible that this may have changed since last year but this is what I am aware as of 2016.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for your answer  @GeekNinja. I think the turnaround here is create a new developer account and use that one to create again the app and the keys for testing purposes. :/

Comment: You bet. Creating a new account is the same as creating a 'new' paypal account, believe it or not. Although 'any' paypal account can be logged in with and used for testing in the developer portal; doesn't matter; even a personal one if you have it.